# Asterisk dialog destruction on attended transfer timeout

Tags: asterisk, telephony

Steps to replicate:

1. Alice receives incoming call from Eve (either from external line or another extension, doesn't matter).
2. Alice makes attended transfer to Bob and hangs up before Bob answers.
3. Bob don't answer his phone.
4. After ${ATXFERNOANSWERTIMEOUT} seconds instead of saying something like `-- Nobody picked up in 30000 ms` and moving to next command in dialplan dialog gets autodestructed and whole conversation ends without ever proceeding through dialplan steps.

log:

```
Executing [291@UserDefault:1] Dial("SIP/290-0000005e", "SIP/291,30,Ttm") in new stack
-- Called SIP/291
-- Started music on hold, class 'default', on SIP/290-0000005e
-- SIP/291-0000005f is ringing
-- SIP/291-0000005f answered SIP/290-0000005e
-- Stopped music on hold on SIP/290-0000005e
-- Started music on hold, class 'default', on SIP/290-0000005e
-- <SIP/291-0000005f> Playing 'pbx-transfer.slin' (language 'ru')
-- Executing [292@UserDefault:1] Dial("Local/292@UserDefault-00000009;2", "SIP/292,30,Ttm") in new stack
-- Called SIP/292
-- Started music on hold, class 'default', on Local/292@UserDefault-00000009;2
-- SIP/292-00000060 is ringing
[May 28 14:56:03] WARNING[-1]: chan_sip.c:4057 __sip_autodestruct: Autodestruct on dialog '328de1203d9af4827ee910cd33209549@sip.######.local' with owner SIP/291-0000005f in place (Method: BYE). Rescheduling destruction for 10000 ms
[May 28 14:56:10] WARNING[-1]: chan_sip.c:4057 __sip_autodestruct: Autodestruct on dialog '328de1203d9af4827ee910cd33209549@sip.######.local' with owner SIP/291-0000005f in place (Method: BYE). Rescheduling destruction for 10000 ms
[May 28 14:56:10] NOTICE[-1]: features.c:3640 feature_request_and_dial: We exceeded our AT-timeout for Local/292@UserDefault-00000009;1
-- Stopped music on hold on Local/292@UserDefault-00000009;2
== Spawn extension (UserDefault, 292, 1) exited non-zero on 'Local/292@UserDefault-00000009;2'
-- SIP/291-00000061 is ringing
[May 28 14:56:16] WARNING[-1]: chan_sip.c:4057 __sip_autodestruct: Autodestruct on dialog '328de1203d9af4827ee910cd33209549@sip.######.local' with owner SIP/291-0000005f in place (Method: BYE). Rescheduling destruction for 10000 ms
[May 28 14:56:22] WARNING[-1]: chan_sip.c:4057 __sip_autodestruct: Autodestruct on dialog '328de1203d9af4827ee910cd33209549@sip.######.local' with owner SIP/291-0000005f in place (Method: BYE). Rescheduling destruction for 10000 ms
[May 28 14:56:25] NOTICE[-1]: features.c:3640 feature_request_and_dial: We exceeded our AT-timeout for SIP/291-00000061
-- Stopped music on hold on SIP/290-0000005e
== Spawn extension (UserDefault, 291, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/290-0000005e'
```

My Asterisk version is 1.8.32.3.